# Excel to store numbers that are 16 digit long

Tags: excel

How do I use the Excel to store numbers that are 16 digit long without the last digit getting reset?

Comment: The superuser have some related answer, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/104811/how-to-put-19-digit-or-more-digit-number-in-a-excel-cell), but as it not related to programming, you should ask in [superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells